# Dotnet Core 3.1 Upgrade error - Method 'GetValidationVisitor' does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have upgraded WEB API dotnet core 2.2 project to 3.1.

inside the `Startup.CS` file I have the following method :

```
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterMvc(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        try
        {
            services
                .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                     options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidationActionFilter));
                })
                .AddControllersAsServices()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                })
                .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
                {
                    fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<MyValidationClass>();
                });
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
        {
            foreach (Exception inner in ex.LoaderExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(inner.Message);
            }
            throw ex;
        }
        return services;
    }
```

Later I use this `RegisterMvc()` method inside `ConfigureServices()` to do the dependency injection.

After upgrading to the new dotnet core, I am getting the following error, and I am clueless about what it's trying to say or how to resolve it:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Method 'GetValidationVisitor' in type    
'FluentValidation.AspNetCore.FluentValidationObjectModelValidator' from assembly  
'FluentValidation.AspNetCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0' 
 does not have an implementation.'
```

Comment: maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026030/fluentvalidation-aspnetcore-is-not-working-in-class-library

Comment: might be some NuGet package issue, could you check consolidate packages in Package manager?

Comment: How did you register your `RegisterMvc`?And what is your `GetValidationVisitor`?Could you debug which line make this error and provide a simple demo that could reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was automatically solved by upgrading the `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` to it's latest version.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/

Answer (score 0):

When you updated and does'nt work.
**Check the references in all the projects** of the solution, becouse is some project is reference to FluentValidation.AspNetCore and no used inside, will generate this Error. In my case I removed the unused reference on a diferent project and problem resolve.